# Is there an Ubuntu program to find anonymous proxy servers?

Tags: software-recommendation, proxy

I've been seeking for a software like proxyfire in Ubuntu to connect to the socks proxy with it. But I found nothing. Now is there anyone to introduce me with a program like that? 
I really need it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no any kind of app for linux!! I mean, till now, you have no any app that click / tap on that and every single packet get pass from that. (Some thing like ProxyFire)

BUT

you can using ProxyChains as a proxyfire. just do that:

```
sudo apt-get install proxychains
```

after that, go to /etc/proxychains.conf, add the following line at the end of file:

```
http      YOUR SERVER IP      PORT      USERNAME          PASSWORD
```

NOTE THAT: use socks4/sock5 instead of HTTP if you are using socks services, but IF you using the HTTPS services, you have to chose the HTTP. AND DO NOT FOR GET COMMENTING THE PREVIOUS LINE "socks4   127.0.0.1    9050"